# could not continue after using command [$ls -f]

Tags: bash, git-bash

i'm new to bash.
i try this command to find folders under current path:

```
$ ls -F | grep "/"
```

but sometimes i would type wrong like grep"\" and it would follow infinite">".
In this situation, i could type everything like ':',w,q,... but just text,i can't type other command.
looks like this:

```
$ ls -F | grep"\"
>
>:wq
>exit
>blablabla
>
```

could anyone tell me how to get away from these terrible ">"?
thanks for saving me

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> That will [signal the end of input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16338/7490).
(also called "[end of transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character)")

That way, you can resume your bash session.

In your case, as [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) mentions below, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> us enough.

I have tested both in a GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys) (from the latest git 2.9.2)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will return to the bash (no logout) after displaying

  ```
  bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
  ```
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will return to the bash immediately.

Comment: Control-C would be better. In many situations, Control-D will end the shell session, while Control-C is more general "oops, cancel that".

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and tested both combinations.

Answer (score 0):

In bash using a backslash normally escapes the character succeeding it.

```
$ echo "\" # this escapes the last double quote but does not complete the command
```

Therefore grep does not think the command is complete and continues allowing input `>`.

```
$ echo "back\slash" | grep "\"" # notice there is a second trailing double quote
```

> To complete the command supply the missing closing double quote
>   (unescaped this time!). <sub>triplee</sub>

Although the previous example completes the command it's actually telling grep to search for a double quote (`"`). To instruct grep to search for a backslash (which I believe was originally intended) then `\` will need to be escaped three times (allowing it to work within double quotes):

```
$ echo "back\slash" | grep "\\\\"
```

If not escaped properly you'll likely get an error `grep: Trailing backslash`. There are of course other ways to accomplish this, although this might help you understand the issue at hand.

Comment: So to "escape", supply the missing closing double quote (unescaped this time!)

Comment: @tripleee: Your comment made my head spin for a minute! Yes, if wanting to escape a double quote then "supply the missing closing double quote (unescaped this time!)" — which in turn completes the command. If wanting to escape a backslash then it needs to be escaped 3x or done another way altogether.

Comment: thank you, it really helps me understand how it happened and how to apply it in other issue